# Workbook becomes hidden when I close another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 workbooks. A, B, and C.

- Workbook A has a hyperlink in it to open B.
- C is just open in the background.
- B has a macro that runs when the file opens that opens a userform.

The userform has two buttons. One is `"Okay"` which put the data into the spreadsheet. The other is `"Save and close"` which does the same, but also saves and closes the workbook.

If I open B from file explorer, everything works fine. However if I open B using the hyperlink in A, and hit the "Save and Close" button, the code works, but then Workbook C becomes hidden. C has nothing to do with A or B.

Any idea why and how to prevent that?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Sheets("Weekly Update").Select
Range("a5").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

**Userform code** of the "Save and Close" Button

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

r = ActiveCell.Row
Cells(r, 1) = TextBox5.Value
Cells(r, 3) = TextBox3.Value
Cells(r, 5) = TextBox4.Value
Cells(r, 7) = TextBox1.Value
Worksheets("Program Financials").Range("F3").Value = UserForm1.TextBox6.Value
Worksheets("Program Schedule").Range("F3").Value = UserForm1.TextBox7.Value
Me.Hide
'okay button code ends here
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

In addition, from userform B I tried calling a sub in A to close to B, and again that worked, however again, C was hidden.

Comment: try replacing both lines `ActiveWorkbook.Save` and `ActiveWorkbook.Close` with `ThisWorkbook.Close Save:=True` , and let me know if that helped you out.

Comment: I get an error that says "Compile Error: Named argument not found"